# In a go server, how can we accept a file gradually, without loading everything in memory?

Tags: go, http

I want to create a HTTP endpoint that clients can send a large file through it.

I don't want to load the whole file in memory, but rather receive, validate and store it in S3 gradually.

I also want to be able to know the total size of the file the client is trying to upload, so to check if it doesn't go beyond a certain limit (in Bytes).

How can I do that in Go?
And if the solution avoids loading everything in memory, where the rest of the file bytes sit (while waiting to be consumed)?

Comment: Use the Content-Length header to find the size. net/http.Request.Body is an io.Reader, just read as much as you like (or not). "where the rest of the file bytes sit (while waiting to be consumed)?" Nowhere. Consult some references of how HTTP works.

Comment: As for where the rest of the bytes you did not read yet are: some sit in the servers socket buffer, some sit in the clients socket buffer and some still sit in the client application or are not even generated there. For more read about how flow control in TCP works.

Comment: If you don't know the size, then you just have to error out when you reach whatever limit you want, for example [`http.MaxBytesReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#MaxBytesReader)

Comment: If you are storing it on `S3` it offers multipart upload for large files where you can send data in chunks and store it. That might be your best bet without reinventing the complete wheel. If you do decide to use it you will need 3 end points 1. to start the upload, 2. actual upload API which you can use to upload the chunks 3. Mark it complet after completion.

Comment: I have not downvoted it but it might be because you are asking how to do and not showing what code did you tried.